# Make a Choice Field-dropdown- as ReadOnly

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form, edit-form

Is there a way to change the EditForm in my SP 2010 site to display a dropdown column but as Read Only,  so the user can not edit that column after the item has been created.I added the below code,  but it works for textfield only, not for dropdown field.

Ref: [here](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/06/02/make-a-text-field-read-only-on-editformaspx-without-spd/)

What am I doing wrong?

```
function SetReadOnly()
  {
   alert('inside setreadonly');
 var inputs = $$('input[title="Customer Name Required Field"]');
   if (null != inputs && inputs.length == 1) 
    {
     var input = inputs[0];
     var label = "<span>" + input.getValue() + "</span>";
      Element.insert(input, {before: label});
       input.hide();
        alert(' customername field is readonly  now');
     }

   alert('inside setreadonly2 opportunity type field');
    var inputopporType = $$('input[title="Opportunity
     Type Required Field"]');
      if (null != inputopporType && inputopporType.length == 1) 
      {
      var inputopporType = inputopporType[0];
        var label = "<span>" + inputopporType.getValue() + "</span>";
          Element.insert(inputopporType, {before: label});
       input.hide();
       alert(' opportunity type field is readonly  now');
         }
 }
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("SetReadOnly");</script>
```

Comment: hi Jussi,as  you suggested,I tried to edit the form, `editform.aspx` in SP D, but I am not able to find the field in the  page & as I told earlier,my page is not responding now!.I am not able to add any  content editor web part on the page. Can you pls tell why I am not able to add CEWP on this `editform.aspx` page?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to set it as read-only, modify the *EditForm.aspx* with SharePoint Designer and change the control into `<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="MyField" runat="server">` control. It will then only render the current value.

Comment: thanks.But when I edited the form in SP D 2010 in one of my previous list forms - `newform.aspx` or `editform.aspx`, due to some reason, I  am not able to add a `content editor` or `CQWP` or any OOTB web parts onto the page.So I didn't create a  copy of this `editform.aspx` or touched the SP D.

Comment: My suggestion was that you do not use your JavaScript code at all, just change the field from drop down into a field that only renders the selected value. Why show disabled drop down to the user as they cannot change it - better to just show the selected value.